# How to Save Asp:Image Element Generated on the Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, base64, client-side

I'm using a JQuery plugin([ScriptCam](http://www.scriptcam.com/)) in order to allow user take snapshots from web camera.

Here's my button with JS code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTakeSnapshot" runat="server" Text="Take SS" OnClientClick="base64_toimage(); return false;" />
```

JS Code:

```
function base64_toimage() {  
    document.getElementById('<%= imgBinary.ClientID %>').src = "data:image/png;base64," + $.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64();  
    document.getElementById('<%= txtImgBinary.ClientID %>').value = $.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64();  
};
```

After user clicks, snapshot is binding to this `Asp:Image` element:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgBinary" runat="server" Width="160" Height="120" />
```

And I also write the binary code to this `Asp:TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImgBinary" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here, what I wanted to do is after user takes snapshot and clicks to last "Save" button, I would save the binary code from `txtImgBinary.Text` value to my `image column` in SQL Server. I did, too, it was all good.

But after I bind the binary value from database in another page, it didn't work. Here's how I did:

```
imgUserPhoto.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/png;base64," + binaryCodeFromDB);
```

I also tried to use same binary code in `PictureBox` element in `Winforms`, but I got that `Argument Exception: Parameter is not valid` error.

I have been trying to do this since yesterday.

So I thought maybe there's something wrong how I save the binary data. Because I'm using the text box as an empty glass, maybe the binary code is changing meanwhile I copy to text box and from it later.

Also, images I save this way has different binary data than another working component's image binary datas.

So I wonder that is there a way to save this image to server after I bind its `src` attribute with JS? If I can save this image, I'll use a temp.jpg image then I will generate its binary code later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't mistaken about the possibility of saving code in the wrong way.

Normally, I was cloning the `base64` array to text box, then I was copying the value in the text box to my image column.

It's a pity that I didn't realize `byte64` array is **not** same with the `byte[]` array.

So before I save this value, I made this little conversation:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(txtImgBinary.Text);
```

Then I store this `bytes` array in my database. Now it's working fine.

---

For those interested, here's how I use this value later:

(For `Asp:Image` element)

```
Image1.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytesValueFromDB));
```

(For `Winforms PictureBox` element)

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytesValueFromDB);
System.Drawing.Image tempImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
string FName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\tempImage.jpg";
tempImage.Save(FName);
imageFileName = FName;
ctlPictureBox.ImageLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\tempImage.jpg";
```